# How to split a sed command into multiple lines

Tags: sed, sh

I have multiple sed command lines which are a bit long. One of them is as follows:

```
sed -i 's/kSchemeScheduleQueue = .*/kSchemeScheduleQueue = '$kSchemeScheduleQueue';/' config.cc
```

I tried to split it by adding `\` in the middle like

```
sed -i 's/kSchemeScheduleQueue = .*/\
          kSchemeScheduleQueue = '$kSchemeScheduleQueue';/' config.cc
```

But this adds a new line and multiple spaces to my file. I've seen from somewhere else that the backslash seems not working well in single-quotes.
I also tried double quotes, the following would work, no additional spaces or new lines, but with bad indentation since my sed commands are in a nested `for` loop while the second line below must be non-indented.

```
sed -i "s/kSchemeScheduleQueue = .*/\
kSchemeScheduleQueue = $kSchemeScheduleQueue;/" config.cc
```

I'm just wondering if there is a simple nice way to split the sed into multiple lines for my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er...  Can you use a shorter variable name? It isn't really the *sed* part of your script that's making it long.

That said, you may be able to optimize a little. Without knowing what the rest of your input file looks like I can't be sure, but one or some of these might work for you.

Before we get started, **a word of warning**.  These sed options (as well as the one in your question) will all fail if the variable contains any characters will will be interpreted or translated by sed. This means the string can't contain a slash (`/`), and also can't contain strings which would turn into regex references (`\1` et al).  To solve this in, for example, bash, you could use the following to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from the string:

```
kSchemeScheduleQueue="${kSchemeScheduleQueue//[^[:alnum:]]/}"
```

First, use double quotes to avoid extra single quotes on the line. With this option, we also assume that the string `=` does not appear somewhere else before the variable you're interested in.

```
sed -i "/kSchemeScheduleQueue = /s/= .*/= $kSchemeScheduleQueue;/" config.cc
```

Next, if you do want to split your lines with actual newlines, you will need to split things into multiple statements, each of which is on a line. Here, we run your substitution in curly braces if the search is successful. This works because whitespace before the `s`ubstitute command is ignored. It's not actually *shorter*, but the lines are shorter.

```
sed -i '/kSchemeScheduleQueue = .*/{;
  s/ = .*/ = '"$kSchemeScheduleQueue"';/;}' config.cc
```

Third option I'll offer is not to use sed, but awk instead. This isn't a heck of a lot shorter than your original sed script, but the length is obviously caused by your variable name. Also, the following does not edit the file in-place, so you'll need to wrap some script around it to handle that part.

```
awk -v s="$kSchemeScheduleQueue" '$1=="kSchemeScheduleQueue"{$3=s} 1' config.cc
```

You could also do this in shell alone (more easily if that shell is bash/ksh/zsh/fish), but that would result in a longer command rather than shorter, though it would eliminate the sed dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/(kSchemeScheduleQueue = ).*/\1'"$kSchemeScheduleQueue"';/' config.c
```

This shortens the command by using a backreference.

Comment: For references, the `-r` option is a GNU sed-ism. The BSD sed equivalent is `-E`, though recent versions of FreeBSD include `-r` as an equivalent option. OSX still uses `-E` to denote ERE. Best to include the platform your solution is intended for, if you provide platform-specific answers.

Comment: @ghoti I always do  provide platform-specific answers.